# Removing right-to-left mark and other unicode characters from input in Python

Tags: python, unicode, right-to-left

I am writing a forum in Python. I want to strip input containing the right-to-left mark and things like that. Suggestions? Possibly a regular expression?

Comment: Why would you want to strip the [BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) or any non-unicode character? Do you hate the rest of the world so much? :)

Comment: @badp A bit late, but...when you're working with any web-elements, use of the RTL unicode mark can sometimes cause drastic breakage in appearance, and because of browsers not handling it in the best of ways, it can go on to break further elements within the page.  I've seen it abused on Steam - it ends up making an absolute mess of normal elements within the page when it's used in a user's name even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to restrict the characters to those of a certain character set, you could encode the string in that character set and just ignore encoding errors:

```
>>> uc = u'aäöüb'
>>> uc.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'ab'
```

Comment: 27     comment = comment.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
comment = '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc', comment.encode = <built-in method encode of str object at 0x11db40>

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
      args = ('ascii', '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc', 0, 1, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
      encoding = 'ascii'
      end = 1
      object = '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'
      reason = 'ordinal not in range(128)'
      start = 0

Comment: Your `comment` doesn't seem to be a unicode object, but a string. It seems to be UTF-8 encoded, so you first need to decode it. With `comment = comment.decode('utf-8')` you convert it to the corresponding unicode object.

Comment: For anyone curious to the end product:

 if uc.decode('utf-8') != uc.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'ignore'): return

Answer (score 1):

The OP, in a hard-to-read comment to another answer, has an example that appears to start like...:

```
comment = comment.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
comment = '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'
```

That of course, with the two statements in this order, would be a different error (the first one tries to access `comment` but only the second one binds that name), but let's assume the two lines are interchanged, as follows:

```
comment = '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'
comment = comment.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

This, which would indeed cause the error the OP seems to have in that hard-to-read comment, is a problem for a different reason: `comment` is a byte string (no leading `u` before the opening quote), but `.encode` applies to a **unicode** string -- so Python first of all tries to make a temporary unicode out of that bytestring with the default codec, `ascii`, and that of course fails because the string is full of non-ascii characters.

Inserting the leading `u` in that literal would work:

```
comment = u'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'
comment = comment.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

(this of course leaves `comment` empty since *all* of its characters are ignored).  Alternatively -- for example if the original byte string comes from some other source, not a literal:

```
comment = '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'
comment = comment.decode('latin-1')
comment = comment.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

here, the second statement explicitly builds the unicode with a codec that seems applicable to this example (just a guess, of course: you can't tell with certainty which codec is supposed to apply from just seeing a bare bytestring!-), then the third one, again, removes all non-ascii characters (and again leaves `comment` empty).

Comment: Sorry for the hard to read comment. Because the user passes the contents of the comment to my script, how do I add the leading u? I am doing: "comment = form.getvalue(key)" and then trying to change it into ascii from there.

Comment: @Earl, if the user is passing you a bytestring with some encoding, you need to use the last snippet I gave in my answer: explicitly decode it to unicode, then encode that unicode back to ascii while skipping non-ascii characters.  But you have to know (or, worst-case, guess!-) what encoding the user is using (guessing _ought_ not to be needed since that information should hopefully be part of the `document-type` header in the HTTP request you're handling!-).

Answer (score 1):

```
"example".replace(u'\u200e', '')
```

You can remove the characters by the hex values with `.replace()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess the set of characters you want to remove from your Unicode strings. Could it be they are all the “[Other, Format](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cf/list.htm)” characters? If yes, you can do:

```
import unicodedata

your_unicode_string= filter(
    lambda c: unicodedata.category(c) != 'Cf',
    your_unicode_string)
```