# Removing text direction marks like RTL, without removing all non-ascii chars

Tags: python, unicode

I'm dealing with an application that allows **unicode characters** as part of the username — which also includes characters that **trigger an RTL text direction**.

The problem: When inserting them into text, they possibly **reverse the whole text** and **break the whole appearance**, also introducing inconsistencies.

How can I deal with that problem – **how can I remove all characters triggering a different text direction than LTR**?

There's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946674/removing-right-to-left-mark-and-other-unicode-characters-from-input-in-python#_=_), but the accepted answer just removes any non-ascii characters like `text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`.

Comment: Figure out which characters they are, and then replace them the same way you would do any other text substitution.

Comment: How about appending an LTR switch if the user name contains an RTL switch? That way you can have both displayed in the right direction. (Though I might have an incomplete idea of how LTR/RTL switching works, never worked with that.)

Comment: @lenz: Nice idea – this actually seems to work. I not only need to append an LTR mark though, but also prepend it.

Comment: Cool. Sounds like a good opportunity to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```py
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inf:
          with open('out/'+filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outf:
            for line in inf.readlines():
              outf.write( line.replace(u'\u200e',''))
```