# Reading File line by line and some lines are read backwards

Tags: python, txt

I want to read the following text from .txt file

```
Title : Linux System Programming Talking Directly to the Kernel and C Library
Publisher ‏: ‎O'Reilly Media
Edition : 2
Year : 2013 
Month : 1
Language ‏ : ‎ English
Paperback ‏ : ‎ 456 pages
ISBN-10 ‏ : ‎ 1449339530
ISBN-13 ‏ : ‎ 978-1449339531
```

using:

```
`f = open("C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/LinuxLab/file.txt",mode = 'r',encoding='utf-8')

for line in f:
    print(line)`
```

the result is the following:

> Title : Linux System Programming Talking Directly to the Kernel and C Library
>
> O'Reilly Media : Publisher ‏ ‎
>
> Edition : 2
>
> Year : 2013
>
> Month : 1
>
> ‏English : Language
>
> 456 pages : Paperback ‏
>
> 1449339530 :  ISBN-10 ‏
>
> ‏ 978-1449339531: ISBN-13

Comment: What do you mean with "backwards"? Looks ok to me.

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you have? How does your output differ from what you expect?

Comment: I just noticed that when i copy the output from console it isn't backwards, but I edited to show what it actually looks like. it isn't a problem of printing only, it reads and stores the line as shown

Comment: Interesting! In your loop, could you try something like `print(line.split(':')[0])` and show the results?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's in your file because of how StackOverflow formats it. But if I'm right, your file contains some `\x200f` and `\x200e` characters. These set the direction of text (`\x200f` indicates right-to-left and `\x200e` indicates left-to-right). If you want to treat everything as L-to-R English text, it probably would be cleaner to strip those out when you read the file. Sorry, I don't know this area well, so I don't know if there's a cleaner way than just `.replace()`.

Comment: (For the curious, these characters leak into the `<meta name="twitter:description">` tag in the HTML of the StackOverflow page, which is how I noticed them.)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270663/removing-text-direction-marks-like-rtl-without-removing-all-non-ascii-chars (which just suggests using `.replace` to remove the RTL indicator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation for this problem:

```
def read_book_details(file_path):
    book_details = {}

    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                key, value = line.split(':', 1)
                book_details[key.strip()] = value.strip()

    return book_details

# Usage example
file_path = 'books.txt'  # Replace with the actual file path
book_details = read_book_details(file_path)

# Print the extracted details
for key, value in book_details.items():
    print(f'{key}: {value}')
```

I have used the key value format to arrange in the given output format.

Answer (score 0):

If your complaint is the empty line you can do this:

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    tex = f.readlines()
    
for line in tex:
    print(line.split('\n')[0])
```

Output:

```
Publisher ‏: ‎O'Reilly Media
Edition : 2
Year : 2013 
Month : 1
Language ‏ : ‎ English
Paperback ‏ : ‎ 456 pages
ISBN-10 ‏ : ‎ 1449339530
ISBN-13 ‏ : ‎ 978-1449339531
```

Comment: I think OP's actual file contains `\x200f` and `\x200e` characters, which control the direction of text display, but these aren't preserved in the body of the question on SO. So copying and pasting from the question doesn't replicate OP's issue.

Comment: @Faultier, right, if I  `print(repr(his_file_copy))`, I see a `\u200f \u200e ` as you mentioned.